# Speed improvement using pre-compiled regex patterns

Tags: java, android, regex, performance

I am writing a parser and tokens are identified by regex.
I use the regexes for each input line, though each regex is in itself short and the matching strings are short as well (a few characters, at most 10).

In [this](http://www.levihackwith.com/javascript-performance-tip-precompile-your-regular-expressions/) post there is a regex speed comparison test for browsers using javascript, showing speed improvements from 0% to 20%.

What is the situation with java and android? Will it make my scanning **significantly** faster to pre compile my regexes? (I know it will not make them *any slower*)
Is there a minimum number of matches that I have to run on the same regex to see any difference at all?

Comment: Your best bet is to test it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sure it is, I am trying to see if someone did it already.

Comment: Not with *your* regexs, in your application. That's what matters.

Comment: Keep in mind that the first step is to improve your regex patterns.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't actually know the regexes in advance, they are set at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind that article is talking about Javascript regexes being stored in a variable or not. This is not the same as precomping the regex, AFAIK.

But, even if it is; to really know which is better, you would have to test the actual regexes being used. If one is used more than a few times, it's possibly worth it.

But if you are going to have many, 'random' regexes being run, it may not be a good idea, as you could end up with lots of regexes sitting around in memory, being lazy, watching TV, eating your snacks...

So, my answer is still; test it in a 'real world' situation. Even if that means releasing your app and modifying it later.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know javascript details, the author called it "preCompiledReplaceRegex" so I assumed that's the way javascrpt pre-compiles regexes.

Comment: @ilomambo Yup; to be honest, I'm a little skeptical about that article. I think something else may be happening there, especially considering it actually made no difference in many browsers. That said, Java is a different story, and the above applies there.